# How to get image URL property from Wikidata item by API?

Tags: java, android, mediawiki-api, google-image-search, wikidata-api

I've made an android app that uses the JSON Google image search API to provide images but I have noticed that Google have stopped supporting it. I have also discovered that Wikidata sometimes provides a image property on some items, however I can't seem to get the URL location of the image using the Wikidata API.

Is there any way to get the image URL property from items in Wikidata?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build URLs from the image property (`Sample.png` in the following example):

```
https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Redirect/file/Sample.png&width=300
```

See Wikimedia Commons' ["Reusing content outside Wikimedia" documentation](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Reusing_content_outside_Wikimedia/technical) for more details.

Comment: it works, but not with `&width` parameter, in that case for different images you will may get a `404`.

Comment: This solution, despite of the 302 redirect (to `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/Sample.png` in the example above) it's more safe than others approach with md5sum (to detect `/a/a7`, that can be subject to changes.

Answer (score 53):

If some Wikidata item (with ID: **Qxxx**) has [image (P18)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P18) property, you can access it by [MediaWiki API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbgetclaims):

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&property=P18&entity=Qxxx
```

The response will include:

```json
"claims": {
        "P18": [{ "mainsnak": { "datavalue": { "value": "img_name.ext" }, "hash": ... }}]
}
```

where **img_name.ext** is the name of the image you are looking for.

The final image URL will be: `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/img_name.ext`, where **a** and **b** are the first and the second chars of [MD5 hashsum](http://www.md5.cz/) of the **img_name.ext** (with all whitespaces replaced by `_`).

**Example:** For item [jaguar (Q35694)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q35694) the API will returns image name "*[Junior-Jaguar-Belize-Zoo.jpg](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=Q35694&property=P18)*", which has MD5 `hashsum("Junior-Jaguar-Belize-Zoo.jpg")` = `213b31ec141dafebe457e49bcd7f9329`, so a=**2** and b=**1**, or the final image URL will be: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Junior-Jaguar-Belize-Zoo.jpg

**Note:** *The MD5 hashsum is for the name of the image file, not the `P18[0].mainsnak.hash` property included in the JSON body.*

Comment: nice! You can also directly get the resized image url like so: https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/thumb.php?width=500&f=Junior-Jaguar-Belize-Zoo.jpg
Nevertheless, beware that requesting a size bigger than the original image size will return an error

Answer (score 0):

I use this PHP function to convert a given image filename into an url for wikipedia commons:

```
function getWikimediaImageURL($aFilename) {
     #-- Example:  $aURLString = getWikimediaImageURL('Fortuna Düsseldorf.svg');    
     $aFilename = str_replace( ' ', '_', $aFilename);
     $md5 = md5($aFilename); 

     return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/" .
            substr($md5,0,1) . 
            "/" .
            substr($md5,0,2). 
            "/" . 
            urlencode($aFilename);
 }
```

Commons is a little bit picky of user agent header. So provide one when downloading (change the User-Agent string according to https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy):

```
$opts = [
    "https" => [
        "method" => "GET",
        "header" => "User-Agent: oolBot/0.0 (https://example.org/coolbot/; coolbot@example.org) generic-library/0.0\r\n" 
    ]
];            
$context = stream_context_create($opts);            
$content = file_get_contents( $pfad , false, $context );
```