# How to get a list of image file names from Wikimedia Commons with just a Wikidata ID

Tags: wikipedia-api, wikidata-api, wikimedia-commons

So the linked answer said how to get one image from Wikidata property P18:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402875/1448813

But how do I get a list of images from wikimedia commons? We have the property P935 which gives us the gallery category name (or page name, I'm not sure what it is). I'm guessing I have to use the [Commons API](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Commons_API) to get the list of relevant images, but I wasn't successful.

For example, I have the [Reichstagsgebäude json of property P935.](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=Q151897&property=P935) What do I do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [categorymembers API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers). It can also be used as a [generator](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Generators) if needed.