# How to read data response from Wikidata API?

Tags: javascript, wikipedia, mediawiki-api, wikidata-api

I am making a ReactJS application to show information about people when they search for it. I am trying to use MediaWiki to get the information about a person from Wikipedia. I am making an API call and the response is very weird. I am getting this whole bunch of "claims" in the API response from which I don't know how to take the useful info

This is the response I get:

[image: response]

Now what should I do with these claims? The information itself is scattered there. For example: "Date of birth" key is in some other claim and the value of "Date of death" is in some other claim. I want to show information like this in my page:

[image: output]

How can I do it? I couldn't get any guide for this.

Answer (score 1):

All information you need for item [Q2038656](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2038656) is in [your response](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=Q2038656). For example:

- P18 is [image](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P18) - located in P18/mainsnak/datavalue/value/**Vinod Khanna at Esha Deol's wedding at ISCKON temple 11 (cropped).jpg** (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393884/how-to-get-image-url-property-from-wikidata-item-by-api/34402875#34402875) how to get the link to the image)
- P19 is [place of birth](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P19) - in P19/mainsnak/datavalue/value/id/**Q1113311** (you can get the name of this item by [this query](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&props=labels&languages=en&ids=Q1113311): *Peshawar*)
- P569 is [date of birth](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P569) - in P569/mainsnak/datavalue/value/time/**+1946-10-06T00:00:00Z**

...continue in the same way for all other properties.