# Wikimedia Commons file not found

Tags: javascript, json, wikipedia, wikimedia

Following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393884/how-to-get-image-url-property-from-wikidata-item-by-api) question, I don't understand why I can't get what I look for: the image of a Wikipedia Article, that of [Le Monde](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Monde).

This request gives me the claims I expect:

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetclaims&entity=Q12461&property=P154

{
    "claims": {
        "P154": [
            {
                "mainsnak": {
                    "snaktype": "value",
                    "property": "P154",
                    "hash": "5566a330c25e15b3997363b88367fbf3e2fda8b1",
                    "datavalue": {
                        "value": "Le Monde.svg",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "datatype": "commonsMedia"
                },
                "type": "statement",
                "id": "q12461$FFF271FE-B26C-4A90-B787-9115024C7F21",
                "rank": "normal"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

With http://www.md5.cz/ I can get the md5 checksum of `Le Monde.svg` which is `92c8a6c9e4755bd38fb7b9c8ac8fcdb6`

However, https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/92/Le%20Monde.svg returns an error:

> File not found: /v1/AUTH_mw/wikipedia-commons-local-public.92/9/92/Le%20Monde.svg.svg

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: How have you extrapolated the full URL? It looks to me like it's actually `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Le_Monde.svg`.

Comment: Thanks! Should all whitespaces always be converted to underscores?

Comment: Also @BenM, are there other replacements I should be aware of?

Comment: Also the error message ends with `.svg.svg`.

Comment: Yeah the error message is a mistake on my part not the source of the problem